# tab change for only clicked element, not all with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, click

Hi i have a simple tabs script:

```
$(".tabs").each(function() {
        $(this).each(function() {
            // FIRST IS ACTIVE
            $(".tabs-nav").find("li").eq(0).addClass("tab-active");
            $(".tabs-content").find("> div, > span, > p").eq(0).nextAll().hide();

            // CHANGE ACTIVE TAB
            $(".tabs-nav li").click(function(event) {

                $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tab-active");
                $(".tabs-content").children().fadeOut();
                $(this).addClass("tab-active");
                getCurrentTab = $(this).index();    
                $(".tabs-content > div, .tabs-content > span, .tabs-content > p").eq(getCurrentTab).fadeIn();

            });

        });
    });
```

And HTML:

```
 <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs-nav">
        <li><a>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Tab 3</a></li>
     </ul>

     <div class="tabs-content">
        <div>Tab 1 Content</div>
        <div>Tab 2 Content</div>
        <div>Tab 3 Content</div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs-nav">
        <li><a>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Tab 3</a></li>
     </ul>

     <div class="tabs-content">
        <div>Tab 1 Content</div>
        <div>Tab 2 Content</div>
        <div>Tab 3 Content</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

When i select a tab in the first tabs div, the event will be at both tabs divs. How can i change the script to select only the tab i click without adding a id?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Only operate on the LIs that are siblings of the clicked element, not all the `.tabs-nav li` elements.

Comment: Why $(this).each(function() { after you have just selected individual tabs with each on the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler you need to limit your operations scope to the relevant `.tabs` element.

```
$(".tabs .tabs-nav li").click(function (event) {
    var $this = $(this).addClass("tab-active"),
        $tab = $this.closest('.tabs'),
        $contents = $tab.find(".tabs-content > *");
    $this.siblings().removeClass("tab-active");

    var index = $this.index();
    var $content = $contents.eq(index).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    $contents.not($content).stop(true, true).fadeOut();

}).filter(':first-child').click();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sSx53/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".tabs").each(function() {
        $(this).each(function() {
            // FIRST IS ACTIVE
            $(".tabs-nav").find("li").eq(0).addClass("tab-active");
            $(".tabs-content").find("> div, > span, > p").eq(0).nextAll().hide();
        });
});
 // CHANGE ACTIVE TAB
$(".tabs-nav li").click(function(event) {
        $(".tabs-nav li").removeClass("tab-active");
        $(".tabs-content").children().fadeOut();
        $(this).addClass("tab-active");
        getCurrentTab = $(this).index();    
        $(".tabs-content > div, .tabs-content > span, .tabs-content > p").eq(getCurrentTab).fadeIn();
        $(this).addClass("tab-active");
});
```